# How to combine all linear transformations into a composite transformation matrix?

Tags: c, matrix, transformation, matrix-multiplication

The matMul function performs a matrix multiplication storing it in Matrix C. For the computeTransformationMatrix function,  the goal is to combine the rotation matrices, scaling matrix, translation matrix, and projection matrix into a single transformation matrix M. All transformation matrices are 4x4 except the projection matrix which is a 2X4 matrix. Constants are properly defined elsewhere, although not shown below. Is the only way to combine the transformations to apply the matMul function once(shown at the very bottom) per transformation matrix until finally creating the composite transformation matrix M?

```
void matMul(Matrix A, Matrix B, int ARows, int ACols, int BCols, Matrix C){
   int i,j,k, sum;
        for(i=0;i<ARows;i++){
        sum = 0;
        for(j=0;j<ACols;j++){
            for(k=0;k<BCols;k++){
            sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }    
}    


void computeTransformationMatrix(Matrix M, float scale, float xt, float yt, float zt) {
// to return final transformation in M
    Matrix P;   // projection matrix
    Matrix S;   // scaling matrix
    Matrix T;   // translation matrix
    Matrix R_X, R_Y, R_Z; //rotation matrices

    // initialize transformation matrices
    rotationMatrixX(ROTATION_ANGLE_X, R_X);
    rotationMatrixY(ROTATION_ANGLE_Y, R_Y);
    rotationMatrixZ(ROTATION_ANGLE_Z, R_Z);
    projectionMatrix(P);
    scalingMatrix(scale, scale, -scale, S);  
    translationMatrix(xt, yt, zt, T);

    Matrix TM1, TM2, TM3, TM4;//store transformed matrices
        matMul(R_X, R_Y, 4, 4, 4, TM1);
        matMul(R_Z, TM1, 4, 4, 4, TM2);
        matMul(T,TM2, 4, 4, 4, TM3);
        matMul(S, TM3, 4, 4, 4, TM4);
        matMul(P, TM4, 2, 4, 4, M);
    }
```

Comment: How else would you do it?  I don't think trying to multiply three matrices simultaneously is very sensible, but that would be about all you could do with non-threaded code.  With threaded code, you might be able to speed up the individual matrix multiplications, but you'd still need to do them in sequence, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you make a "canned" combination of the three rotation matrices.

Using this formula from [EulerAngles/wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) for rotating first in X, then Y, then Z:
[image]

c and s mean cosin and sin of the angles where 1 is the angle for x, 2 for y, 3 for z.

This should cut down your computation time substantially.

If you want to perform the rotations in a different order, there are other matrices described on the web page.